# Add and remove class javascript loop

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation

I have this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#aa").addClass("animatedaa fadeIn");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#aa").removeClass("animatedaa fadeIn"),
                $("#aa").addClass("animatedaaout fadeOut");
    }, 3500);

    $("#bb").addClass("animatedbb fadeIn");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#bb").removeClass("animatedbb fadeIn"),
                $("#bb").addClass("animatedbbout fadeOut");
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

How can I achieve to make infinite loop, so this events "addClass" and "removeClass" repeat infinite?

Best regards and thank you for your answers.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. By SO rules, please include any relevant code in the question itself. You are welcome to *additionally* link it somewhere else (such as jsbin.com, jsfiddle.com, sqlfiddle.com, rubular.com), but the readers should be able to understand your question without visiting any external links.

Comment: Create a function for it. And call itself at the end of the function.

Comment: @RLam can you please explain me more how to do it?

Comment: @AleksandarPopovic Somthing like this [https://jsfiddle.net/c4pn8jg3/](https://jsfiddle.net/c4pn8jg3/)

Comment: @AleksandarPopovic: I have updated my answer based after re-analysing your question

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. `setInterval` will create a timer that will execute indefinitely until `clearInterval` is called.

For example:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $("#aa").removeClass("animatedaa fadeIn"),
    $("#aa").addClass("animatedaaout fadeOut");
}, 3500);
```

**Edit:** after re-analysing your question, I think the following code would do what you need. Basically the code uses `setInterval` to schedule a timer that will execute every 10 seconds the two sets of `addClass`/`removeClass` calls. You can tweak the duration to match what you need, however don't reduce it below 5 seconds, otherwise it create problems due to conflicts with the `setTimeout` call for `#bb`.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#aa").addClass("animatedaa fadeIn");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#aa").removeClass("animatedaa fadeIn"),
        $("#aa").addClass("animatedaaout fadeOut");
    }, 3500);

    $("#bb").addClass("animatedbb fadeIn");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#bb").removeClass("animatedbb fadeIn"),
        $("#bb").addClass("animatedbbout fadeOut");
    }, 5000);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m0ff74mh/6/) color stop changing. why not it is changing after and after

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#aa').toggleClass('animatedaa fadeIn');
}, 3500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document.ready(function(){    // if you want to call this function on document ready
  addRemoveClass();

}));

function addRemoveClass(){
  $("#aa").addClass("animatedaa fadeIn");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#aa").removeClass("animatedaa fadeIn"),
                $("#aa").addClass("animatedaaout fadeOut");
    }, 3500);

    $("#bb").addClass("animatedbb fadeIn");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#bb").removeClass("animatedbb fadeIn"),
                $("#bb").addClass("animatedbbout fadeOut");
    }, 5000);

    addRemoveClass();
}

</script>
```

**updated**

```
$(document).ready(function(){    // if you want to call this function on document ready
      addRemoveClass();

    });
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m0ff74mh/7/)**

Comment: Thank you @ozul, but WHen I implement this, from some reason it is not working :-/

Comment: I do not any error on console. It just does not work, does not add and remove classes. But in my IDE I get error: "Unresolved function or method () "

Comment: actually, there is an error:
TypeError: document.ready is not a function
 

$(document.ready(function(){    // if you want to call this function on document...

Comment: It should be `$(document).ready(function(){
     addRemoveClass();
});`

Comment: @AleksandarPopovic My ans is not same as ozil's one. Look at the end of the answer, it should be `});` but not `}));`

Comment: @RLam I see, but it is not working. Here is jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/2f4e669L/

Comment: @ozil is there any way to make it in loop... so it does this color change from the begining every time to infinity?

Comment: @ Aleksandar Popovic it is running but you don't see the effect, because code is like that way

Comment: @ Aleksandar Popovic check the demo in `answer`

Answer (score 0):

To make an infinite execution of your code you should use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeou()` which execute an event only once , here's what you need:

```js
    $("#aa").addClass("animatedaa fadeIn");
        console.log("aa***animatedaaout fadeIn");
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#aa").removeClass("animatedaa fadeIn"),
                $("#aa").addClass("animatedaaout fadeOut");
       console.log("aa***animatedaaout fadeOut");
    }, 3500);

    $("#bb").addClass("animatedbb fadeIn");
console.log("bb***animatedaaout fadeIn");
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#bb").removeClass("animatedbb fadeIn"),
                $("#bb").addClass("animatedbbout fadeOut");
        console.log("bb***animatedaaout fadeOut");
    }, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="aa"></div>
<div id="bb"></div>
```

You can see the result in the console.

**EDIT:**

To make it infinite loop you have to wrap all these code inside a function and use only one `setInterval()`, because using more than one can damage your program and use a `setTimeout()` to delay the second pragragh `bb` class Changes, this is the function that I came up with:

```
function removeClass() {
    $("#aa").addClass("animatedpone fadeIn");
    $("#bb").addClass("animatedptwo fadeIn");
    var fadeIn = true;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (fadeIn === true) {
            $("#aa").removeClass("animatedpone fadeIn");
            $("#aa").addClass("animatedponeout fadeOut");
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#bb").removeClass("animatedptwo fadeIn");
                $("#bb").addClass("animatedponeout fadeOut");
            }, 1000);
            fadeIn = false;
            } else {
            $("#aa").removeClass("animatedpone fadeOut");
            $("#aa").addClass("animatedponein fadeIn");
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#bb").removeClass("animatedptwo fadeOut");
                $("#bb").addClass("animatedponein fadeIn");
            }, 1000);
            fadeIn = true;
        };
    }, 5000);
}
```

You can see the results in **[this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/vezh9v0z/)**

Comment: @AleksandarPopovic Yes of course it whould not work, take a look at my EDIT.

Comment: Thanks my friend. 
How can I make this function to work infinite, actually to non-stop show and remove classes?

Comment: @AleksandarPopovic take a look at my EDIT, and use only one `setInterval()` to avoid any timing problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addRemoveClass(){
  $("#aa").show('slow');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#aa").show('slow').hide('slow');
        
    }, 3500);

    $("#bb").show('slow');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#bb").show('slow').hide('slow');
        addRemoveClass();
    }, 5000);

    
}


      addRemoveClass();



Try this.
I haven't used the classes but simple Show and Hide methods of the jQuery. You can change it according to your need.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="aa" class="">asdasdad</p>
<p id="bb" class="">asdasd</p>
```